# on off function with php

Tags: php, mysql

I am actually still learning PHP. I don't know what's really happening but I can't figure out a problem. Maybe it's because of PHP update or anything.

I actually made a simple PHP debugger and with print_r(); and thought I will connect it with the database so that I can turn off the switch or the actual debug code whenever I want to. I don't know the reason but it's not working. I'm providing everything that can figure out the problem if I missed anything please let me know.
Here's the actual code from different page I putted it together actually.

```html
//site Setup: (this is on the database connection file)
$debug = data_setting_value($dbc, 'debug-status');

//This one is from the function file
function data_setting_value($dbc, $id) {
 
  $q = "SELECT * FROM settings WHERE id = 'debug-id'";
  $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

  $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);

  return $data['value'];
}

// this one is from the index file

 <?php if ($debug == 1) { ?>
  <button id="btn-debug" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-bug"></i></button>
 <?php } ?>
}
```

[Database file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LghTr.png)

Comment: First check for error ..  try adding var_dump( $mysqli->error); after your mysqli_query ..

Comment: well of course I won't be asking for help without trying various things myself, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

int the line `$q = "SELECT * FROM settings WHERE id = 'debug-id'";` you use `'debug-id'` change it to $id.

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM settings WHERE id = '".$id."'";
```

Comment: I actually tried kind of like this 
$q = "SELECT * FROM settings WHERE id = '$id'";
But didn't know it can be used like this. It worked really really thanks :)

Comment: glad i could help :)